# JRFileVirtualizer and JRXlsxExporter

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports

How to export a large xlsx file using JasperReport with JRFileVirtualizer? I need some sample codes

Here's mine, but failed

```
package afs.view.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporterParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.ooxml.JRXlsxExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFileVirtualizer;

public class ExcelPaymentPremiControl extends HttpServlet {
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
                                                           IOException {
        response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
        /*PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head><title>ExcelPaymentPremiControl</title></head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<p>The servlet has received a GET. This is the reply.</p>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.close();*/

        System.out.println("================================");
        System.out.println("ExcelPaymentPremiControl_servlet");
        System.out.println("================================");

        try{
            String invoice_no = request.getParameter("invoice_no");
            String binding_no = request.getParameter("binding_no");
            String ref = request.getParameter("ref");
            String ref_reclass = request.getParameter("ref_reclass");
            String reinsured_name = request.getParameter("reinsured_name");
            String reinsurance_name = request.getParameter("reinsurance_name");
            String report = "C://jsreport/Binding/PaymentPremiControlExcel.jasper";

            Map map = new HashMap();
            map.put("P_INVOICE_NO", invoice_no);
            map.put("P_BINDING_NO", binding_no);
            map.put("P_REF", ref);
            map.put("P_REF_RECLASS", ref_reclass);
            map.put("P_REINSURED_NAME", reinsured_name);
            map.put("P_REINSURANCE_NAME", reinsurance_name);

            JRFileVirtualizer jRFileVirtualizer = new JRFileVirtualizer(1000, report);
            jRFileVirtualizer.setReadOnly(false);
            map.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, jRFileVirtualizer);

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds =(DataSource)initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/Simasre-dev-ORDBMSDS"); // get from your application module configuration
            Connection conn = ds.getConnection(); 

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, map, conn); //Here is line 77
            OutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();

            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachement; filename=\"ReportPaymentPremiControl.xlsx\"");

            JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IGNORE_PAGE_MARGINS, Boolean.FALSE);  
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.TRUE); 
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS, Boolean.FALSE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BORDER, Boolean.FALSE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, ouputStream);

            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("FILLING TIME ExcelPaymentPremiControl: "+((end-start)/1000)+" second(s)");

            try{
                exporter.exportReport();
                jRFileVirtualizer.cleanup();
            }catch(JRException jre){
                jre.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                if(ouputStream != null){
                    try{
                        ouputStream.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                conn.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        response.getOutputStream().close();
        response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
    }
}
```

Here is the error stacktrace. The code was run just fine when exporting a xlsx file with small amount of row. But occurred when I was trying to export  40000++ rows xlsx files

```
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
  at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFileVirtualizer.pageOut(JRFileVirtualizer.java:113)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.virtualizeData(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:664)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.evict(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:485)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.registerObject(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:440)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.register(VirtualizableElementList.java:249)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.preAdd(VirtualizableElementList.java:298)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.add(VirtualizableElementList.java:333)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.add(VirtualizableElementList.java:349)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.VirtualizableElementList.add(VirtualizableElementList.java:125)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRVirtualPrintPage.addElement(JRVirtualPrintPage.java:136)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2116)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2067)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:778)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportContent(JRVerticalFiller.java:308)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:155)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)
  at afs.view.servlets.ExcelPaymentPremiControl.doGet(ExcelPaymentPremiControl.java:77)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
  at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:175)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
  at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:313)
  at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:413)
  at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
  at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:161)
  at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
  at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:136)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
  at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.virtualizeData(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:669)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.evict(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:485)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.registerObject(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:440)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.register(VirtualizableElementList.java:249)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.preAdd(VirtualizableElementList.java:298)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.add(VirtualizableElementList.java:333)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.ElementsBlock.add(VirtualizableElementList.java:349)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.VirtualizableElementList.add(VirtualizableElementList.java:125)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRVirtualPrintPage.addElement(JRVirtualPrintPage.java:136)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2116)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2067)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:778)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportContent(JRVerticalFiller.java:308)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:155)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)
  at afs.view.servlets.ExcelPaymentPremiControl.doGet(ExcelPaymentPremiControl.java:77)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
  at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:175)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
  at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:111)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:313)
  at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:413)
  at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:94)
  at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:161)
  at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
  at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:136)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
  at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
  at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
  at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
  at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFileVirtualizer.pageOut(JRFileVirtualizer.java:113)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.virtualizeData(JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer.java:664)
  ... 50 more
```

The tags is the environments those I'm using right now

Thanks before

Comment: The [search on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjasper-reports%5D+JRFileVirtualizer+) gives several samples of using *JRVirtualizer*

Answer (score 0):

You have the following lines in your code:

```
            String report = "C://jsreport/Binding/PaymentPremiControlExcel.jasper";
...
            JRFileVirtualizer jRFileVirtualizer = new JRFileVirtualizer(1000, report);
```

If you take a look at [the Javadoc of the JRFileVirtualizer constructor](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JRFileVirtualizer.html#JRFileVirtualizer(int,%20java.lang.String)), you'll see that the second argument should be the path of the folder where the virtualizer is to create temporary files.  You are passing the path to the compiled report, which is not even a folder (whence the error).  Try something like `"C://temp"` or some path where the virtualizer can create temporary files.

Comment: You're right. I wonder if that's really the source of the problem. I'll try this later and update the result immediately. Thanks for pointing it out.